# how to redirect sub pages to www to non-www from htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

I am trying to redirect my subpage to a non-www but I get duplicate URLs of the same page.

**What I want to implement**

```
https://www.example.com/category/webs => https://example.com/category/webs
http://example.com/category/webs => https://example.com/category/webs
http://www.example.com/category/webs => https://example.com/category/webs
```

> .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+) category-list.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

With this current code, my root domain redirects perfectly. but not subpages! I read many articles but not helping

Answer (score 1):

The rule you have posted already does this, but your rules are in the wrong order. You need to redirect the request *before* rewriting the request to `category-list.php`. Otherwise, "subpages" will be redirected to `category-list.php`, which is what I assume is happening.

*Aside:* You should escape the *literal hyphen* in the character class `([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)`, or move this to the start or end of the character class, to negate its special meaning. You should also include the end-of-string anchor at the end of the regex, otherwise it will successfully match too much (potentially creating duplicate content).

Try it like this instead:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Canonical redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite request
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ category-list.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, this worked to redirect all pages to HTTPS from HTTP but still getting to duplicate URLs for the same page as a www and a non-www, how do I redirect www one to a non-www.

Comment: @SahilHansda The rule above should already redirect anything other than `example.com` (which naturally includes the www subdomain) to `example.com`. Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. You can try changing the _condition_ `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$` to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]` - now it specifically targets the www subdomain (but that really shouldn't make any difference). How is the www subdomain configured in the server config?

Comment: Did this, same results [check here](https://freetools.seobility.net/en/redirectcheck/check?url=refinedfeed.com&expected=https) Maybe this is because of my dynamic page which I rewrite its URL forcefully?

Comment: @SahilHansda The problem doesn't just apply to `www.example.com/category/<something>` URLs, but to `www.example.com/<something>` as well. It doesn't look like your `.htaccess` file is doing anything?! HTTP to HTTPS is handled by HSTS (it's not "redirected" by this rule). The "category" rewrite isn't doing anything. `/category/india` results in a different response to `/category-list.php?id=india` (just a 404). `/category-list.php` results in a 404. Something else must be redirecting the root www to non-www. (You are on a LiteSpeed server, not Apache.) Presumably the `.htaccess` file is in the

Comment: @SahilHansda (My comment was truncated for some reason...) Presumably the `.htaccess` file is in the document root? I'm assuming you don't have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? However, you have other URLs that are being routed somehow, eg. `/posts/drone-taxi-pura-ho-jayega-ye-sapna-bhi` - how are you doing this?